# Magento2 module not getting detected after installing via composer

Tags: magento2

Magento2 I am confused about why the module is not getting deducted after installing via the composer. When I run the cmd of setup upgrade the module is not getting configured.

Comment: Could be permission related? Also try composer dump autoloader.

Answer (score 0):

please run this commnad to check its showing in diabled module or not:

```
php bin/magento module:s
```

alsp go to app/etc/config.php and check module exist or not.

Comment: Not exist in config.php

Comment: did you run the commmand?